# C# - Report progress of Woocommerce.net call

Tags: c#, woocommerce, rest, progress

I am working on a small C# application using Woocommerce.net library to make RESP API calls. My goal here is to retrieve all products from my online store which I have done. However, while the products are being retrieved, I want to show the user progress with a progress bar preferably. Here is the code I am using for retrieving products.

```
RestAPI rest = new RestAPI("https://www.store.ca/wp-json/wc/v3/", "key", "key");
            WCObject wc = new WCObject(rest);

            //Get all products

            products = new List<Product>();
            Dictionary<string, string> dic1 = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            dic1.Add("per_page", "100");
            int pageNumber1 = 1;
            dic1.Add("page", pageNumber1.ToString());

            bool endWhile1 = false;
            while (!endWhile1)
            {
                var productsTemp = await wc.Product.GetAll(dic1);
                
                if (productsTemp.Count > 0)
                {
                    products.AddRange(productsTemp);
                    pageNumber1++;
                    dic1["page"] = pageNumber1.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    endWhile1 = true;
                }
            }
```

Is there any way possible to report back progress for such call. I couldn't find anything related to this. I came across `IProgress<int>` but I believe that would not work in this scenario.

Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You read objects 'per page'.
1.If you can get product count please do it first (version 3 had count method)
2. progress step will be (page number * 100 items) which you can notify right after addRange

Comment: so am I essentially retreiving 1 item per page to report back the progress? Because I only have about 24 products as of now. So with 100 per page, there wont be any progress step. After the first run, it will go straight to 100 from 0. If I am not mistaken.

Comment: Small amounts of items are not a problem.
IMHO, the quick response of the app is worth more than the extra features.
 I thought there were more products and the user would get a chance to see the progress bar ;).
These kinds of ux elements inform about long-term state processes - in progress.
Try to avoid long operations. If this is not critical, leave the progress bar for now and move on to the next function.